# Eclipse Kepler Symfony Service Locator on $this Autocompletion

Tags: php, symfony, code-completion, eclipse-kepler

I am new in Symfony2. Yesterday I download Eclipse Kepler 4.3 and installed the pdt plugins from http://p2-dev.pdt-extensions.org.

After creating a Symfony Project in Eclipse I read some tutorials. 
In my Controller LoginController I want to use `$this->createFormBuilder` method.

But I have no code completion.

I can enter the Controller class by holding ctrl and click with mouse on class name on the line with `extends Controller`, in addition I get code completion if I type `self::`.

But I get nothing if I type `$this->`.

Anyone know what can be the problem?
The project nature is as follows in .project file:

```
<natures>
    <nature>org.eclipse.php.core.PHPNature</nature>
    <nature>org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.core.nature</nature>
    <nature>com.dubture.composer.core.composerNature</nature>
    <nature>com.dubture.symfony.core.symfonyNature</nature>
    <nature>com.dubture.doctrine.core.doctrineNature</nature>
</natures>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found the solution on my self... 
The problem was `vendor` and `src` folders where not in the build path of my symfony project.
Simply add them to build path and now it works.